# Get String and Drawable from resource file into Fragment View Model class

Tags: java, resources, fragment, android-viewmodel

how can I get drawable from drawable resource file into my fragment view model and  get String like text not like Integer identifier, also from my resource files, java .How  can I get access to my resource files from Fragment View Model class.

Comment: Can you please add some more details and code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.